# Accessing variables in javascript revealing prototype pattern

Tags: javascript

```
var tool = function (bID, $element) {
    this.bID = bID || 0;
    this.$element = $element || false;
    this.element = $element[0] || false;
};

tool.prototype = function () {

    // if this.bID == 'x' && this.$element ? ...

}();
```

How do I access the vars set initially in prototype functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tool = function (bID) {
    this.bID = bID || 0;
};

let testTool = new tool(5);

tool.prototype.logging = function () {
    console.log(this.bID)
};

testTool.logging();
```

`tool.prototype` is a container for all properties/attributes for tool, in other words you cannot do what you're doing below

```
tool.prototype = function () {

    // if this.bID == 'x' && this.$element ? ...

}();
```

Instead assign the function expression into a variable, in my case `logging`, then invoke it using the object you created, else what you think `this` is if without object created?

**UPDATES**

```
var tool = function (bID = 'x') {
    this.bID = bID || 0;
};

//console.log(tool.prototype.logging());//TypeError: tool.prototype.logging is not a function


let somefunc = function(toolParam) { 
  if(toolParam.bID === 'x'){
    tool.prototype.logging = function () {
      return console.log(this.bID)
    };
  }
}

let testTool = new tool();

    somefunc(testTool);

console.log(tool.prototype.logging)
//ƒ () {
//        return console.log(this.bID);
//    }
```

Comment: I'm creating the object later but I need to have some conditional code in the prorotype functions which requires accessing the properties of the tool. Like for example I want to check if the element exists otherwise do not expose any functions

Comment: @3zzy: Kindly have a look at my **updates**, see if i understand clearly what you're referring to?